# How do I send a DHCP request to find DHCP server IP address? Is this possible?

Tags: python, dhcp

Is it possible to write a small script that will send out a DHCP broadcast request and find the DHCP server address?

I need this for a project, but my research led me to believe that you cannot do this on Windows? I would need a small script for OSX, Linux and Windows.

Comment: Why can't you run `ipconfig`, for example, and extract the gateway information?

Answer (score 2):

Okay, I'm going to make the assumption that your default gateway is configured to point at your DHCP server. I found the following package and was able to get my default gateway:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import netifaces

gateway_info = netifaces.gateways()
print(gateway_info)
```

I of course first had to install the `netifaces` module via pip:

$> pip install --user netifaces

Code returns the following:

$> ./test3.py

{'default': {2: ('192.168.0.1', 'en0')}, 2: [('192.168.0.1', 'en0', True)]}

I hope this helps.

Best regards,

Aaron C.

Comment: I believe OP wants the IP address of the **DHCP Server** not the client's IP.

Comment: @Gator_Python I believe you are right. I changed my answer. Assuming his/her default gateway is pointed at the DHCP server then my changes should work. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're asking an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem): You want to know how to find the DHCP IP address on windows, via python?

There is a solution on SuperUser for [obtaining DHCP server ip from the command line](https://superuser.com/questions/314145/how-to-find-my-dhcp-server-ip-address-via-a-command-prompt-in-windows/314147). You can wrap `ipconfig /all` with `subprocess` and then parse the output:

```
import subprocess  # Runs a command on the cmd line

res = subprocess.check_output("ipconfig /all")
```